# How to disable css framework for certain elements or sections?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a large project that is using Zurb Foundation for various styles. However, I built a large one-off section of the site outside of the context of this project in my editor, and when I migrated the html/css into it, the Foundation styles are overriding a *lot* of it, causing it to be totally unusable.

I am wondering if there is a way to disable a framework like bootstrap or foundation for certain elements and children? That is my ideal fix.

So far I am giving all elements inside the section in question a class that is using unset:all; in the css, and that is working to a large degree, but I will still have a long way to go in inspecting and fixing whatever other issues are arising in the styling.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had the same problem and I solved that with a library created by Yahoo called YUI. More specifically, it is a piece of that library that works on resetting CSS configurations for a specific div. You can find it in https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/

In this case, you should follow the recommendations of "CSS Reset Contextually", and you might need to use the "!important" for the properties to be applied in the section, when coding the specific CSS.